# Can a rotary incremental encoder, count more steps due to interferences

Tags: encoder, interference

I have an incremental encoder having differential signals A-NotA, B-NotB I-NotI, that apparently randomly seems to count more impulses. It is possible to have more impulses due to electrical interferences ( IMO not because of the differential outputs ) or can this happen?
The encoder is a Baumer BHK 16.05A.1024-I2-5 and a datasheet can be found here http://www.pdfdoc.ru/process-control/sensors-and-transducers/rotary-encoders/baumer/bdk-min-shaft-encoder-1024ppr-ttl-o-p-bdk-16-05a-1024-5-4-499-7598

The wiring is done by 5m cable with shield connected to ground at a single point ( near the encoder ) and we are not using twisted pairs.

Comment: Data sheet link?

Comment: @Andyaka I added more information in the question

Comment: I can't get the link to work

Comment: @Andyaka strange, it worked on my side. Anyway I replaced with another link.

Comment: Of course it's possible that electromagnetic interference is causing extraneous counts. You need to examine the signals with an oscilloscope in order to diagnose this.

Comment: @DaveTweed even a long sequence always in the same direction?

Comment: It depends on the sophistication of the logic connected to the encoder. There are many simple logic designs that can be forced to count continuously, because they fail to ignore "illegal" transitions created by noise. And it's possible to fool even a sophisticated decoder if the noise is induced into both lines with sufficient phase shift between them.

Comment: @DaveTweed the decoder is from a branded robot, so I suppose it should be smart enough. So can we confirm, if the decoder is good enought, noise should be really sophisticated to generate a monodirectional quote shift.

Comment: No, you can't.  Just becsuse it has a brand name on it doesn't mean that part wasn't designed at 4:30 on a Friday and never touched again because it seemed to work.  Reviews *should* catch things like that, but history is full of leakage.  Perhaps you could experiment and try to find ways to cause false counts.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal for a rotary encoder to go through the following sequence:

```
- A low     and B low
* A low     and B jittery
- A low     and B high
* A jittery and B high
- A high    and B high
* A high    and B jittery
- A high    and B low
* A jittery and B low
```

From a decoding perspective, one may either use the states marked with dashes or with asterisks.  If one uses the states marked with dashes, then when the encoder is near a switching threshold, it may appear to jitter back and forth between two positions.  If the decoder is designed correctly the overall rotation should be correct, since repeated jitters will cancel out, but a +/- 1 unit jitter may be annoying.  If one uses the states marked with asterisks, apparent jitter will be eliminated (once an input changes, all future changes on that input will be ignored until the other input changes) but backlash will be increased by a tick.

If the decoding logic isn't implemented properly, it's possible for the jitter to cause unwanted counts in such a fashion that they don't cancel, but the solution in that case is to fix the decoding logic.